# How import file from computer to docker containers with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a problem with my docker container. I need to import data, something like `.csv` file from my computer to docker container, but I don't know how. I found a command like "docker insert" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Docker volumes.

```
docker run -i -t -v /home/user/stuff:/data ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Where in this example /home/user/stuff is a directory OUTSIDE the container and /data is the directory where that content will be located INSIDE the container.